# What is the function of this black conical part of a switchboard?

Tags: electrical

I notice a black structure (in indicated inside the orange circle) on top of a electrical switchboard. The enclosure is manufactured by this company https://www.brenclosures.com.au/product-overview/ but I cannot find any info on their website. I would like to know its purpose out of curiosity.

[image]

Comment: Some sort of radio aerial

Comment: Probably an antenna to send sensor or problem reports to a central site.  My power company has similar type receivers on their poles for their smart meters.

Comment: My bet would be on it being a WiFi antenna for remote readings of power usage. If you were to open the panel door (do _NOT_ do this if it's not yours!) you would find power monitoring equipment in addition to the usual collection of circuit breakers.

Comment: Probably covers an antenna for a GPRS radio, used to monitor the hardware.

Comment: The box, whatever is inside it, and the crudely attached antenna were assembled by their owner.  There is nowhere you can look up what it all amounts to.  At a high level, the antenna helps gizmos in the box communicate with the gizmo mothership.  Perhaps to monitor the gizmo health, perhaps in an effort at world domination .... we can't tell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a cell phone antenna - for a data connection.

It's not **part** of the enclosure, it's merely **attached to** it.

I doubt it's this brand (no affiliation and in fact never heard of them, just went looking for an image I could link), because there are many that look similar, but here's one example of a 3G/4G LTE antenna:

[image: Laird 3G/4G antenna from ArcAntenna.com]

Comment: Thank you for the answer!